# Get data after certain word in a line?

Tags: c#

Let's say my string called hello equaled "EJFEWJFWEFOWEFOJWEOFWEF LINK http://google.com"

I want to basically get whatever's after "LINK " which in this case is "http://google.com".

Please note "EJFEWJFWEFOWEFOJWEOFWEF" is always random & always has a random length.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Assuming your string is ALWAYS formatted the way you demonstrated, try this: `string link = hello.Substring(hello.IndexOf(" LINK ") + 6, hello.Length - hello.IndexOf(" LINK ") - 6);`. Keep in mind, you should perform lots of checks, just in case though.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I've tried returning the index (by counting up the characters) but in reality it won't work obviously since the data is always random. I'm not sure what to use here man which is why i'm asking this question?

Comment: @icemanind Thanks man, you've solved it.

Answer (score 1):

A sloppy way that works:

```
string a = "EJFEWJFWEFOWEFOJWEOFWEF LINK http://google.com";
string[] stuff = a.Split(' ');
Console.WriteLine(stuff[Array.IndexOf(stuff, "LINK") + 1]);
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/vrxS8z).

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are looking for is this:

```
string link = hello.Substring(hello.IndexOf(" LINK ") + 6, hello.Length - hello.IndexOf(" LINK ") - 6);
```

I'd like to break it down though so you actually understand why it works. I'm going to rewrite it here, in simpler blocks:

```
string hello = "EJFEWJFWEFOWEFOJWEOFWEF LINK http://google.com";
int ndx = hello.IndexOf(" LINK "); // Returns the position of the string " LINK "
string link = hello.Substring(ndx +6, hello.Length - ndx - 6); // Extracts everything after " LINK "
```

The IndexOf method search for a string within a string and returns the 0-based position or -1 if its not found. Substring is a method that extracts part of a string from another string. We are extracting, in this case, everything after the word " LINK ".

What you need to be careful of and check:

```
1. What if LINK doesn't exist?
2. What if the string isn't always upper case?
3. What if the string is null or empty?
```